# How to replace variable substrings across a pandas dataframe column that are defined by the column after?

Tags: python, string, pandas, str-replace

I have a large pandas dataframe `df1` that contains whole user agents in `col1` and the contained Chrome version in `col2` (`col2` is generated based on regex patterns applied to `col1`).

```
col1, col2
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Chrome/14.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36, Chrome/14
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Chrome/15.0.2743.98 Safari/537.36, Chrome/15
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Chrome/22 Safari/537.36, None
```

I want to replace the Chrome version number in `col1` with a random integer above a threshold if the same number in `col2` is below this threshold. Note that `col2` is `None` if the threshold is met.

I know that in this context, I need to `df.apply` with `axis = 1` in order to access both column values at the same time.

However, when I do:

```
df1.loc[(df1.col2 is not None), 'col1'] = 
         df1.apply(lambda x: x['col1'].replace(x['col2'], randint(20, 60)), axis=1)
```

I yield:

```
TypeError: ('expected a string or other character buffer object', u'occurred at index 0')
```

**How to replace variable substrings across a pandas dataframe column that are defined by the column after?**

Solutions that did not work for me (reason):
[Python Pandas removing substring using another column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34775455/6060083) (too slow)
[replace substring in pandas data frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32902941/6060083) (not applicable to variable substrings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's absolutely no need for `apply`. Use `str.replace` with a callback:

```
from random import randint

m = df.col2.notna()
df.loc[m, 'col1'] = df.loc[m, 'col1'].str.replace(
     r'(?<=Chrome/).*?(?=\s)', lambda x: str(randint(20, 60))
)
```

```
df
                                                col1       col2
0  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Chrome/51 Safa...  Chrome/14
1  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Chrome/26 Safa...  Chrome/15
2  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Chrome/22 Safa...       None
```