# How do I replace the value in a cell that contains certain words in Python Panda like in Excel?

Tags: python

I have my data as

| Age | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| 2 Year(s) | Male |
| 3 Month(s) | Male |
| 2 Day (s) | Female |

And I want to make it to

| Age | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Male |
| Below 1 year | Male |
| Below 1 year | Female |

Comment: What I was looking for was, if the cell contain 'Year(s)' then keep the digit only, if it contains Month(s) or Hour(s) then change to Below 1 year. Something like that or anything that works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace substring in pandas data frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902837/replace-substring-in-pandas-data-frame-column)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function. In your case:

```py
df.Age.replace({
    "2 Year(s)": "2",
    "3 Month(s)": "Below 1 year",
    ...
    },
    inplace=True
)
```

Comment: can't do that for the rest of the 30000 entries :/

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I did this, I copy pasted the actual code from my code editor

```
#split Patient Age and append back to master list
alldata[['Age', 'Unit']] = alldata['Patient Age'].str.split(' ', expand=True)

#Separate into subdata of Years, Months, Days and Hours
dfunit = alldata.groupby(['Unit'])
dfyears = dfunit.get_group('Year(s)')
dfmonths = dfunit.get_group('Month(s)')
dfdays = dfunit.get_group('Day(s)')
dfhours = dfunit.get_group('Hour(s)')


#Replace value of Mpnths, Days and Hours with 0
dfmonths['Age'] = dfmonths['Age'].str.replace('\d', '0')
dfdays['Age'] = dfdays['Age'].str.replace('\d', '0')
dfhours['Age'] = dfhours['Age'].str.replace('\d', '0')


#Combine sublist back to master list
newdata = dfyears.append(dfmonths).append(dfdays).append(dfhours)

#Convert value in Age to int
newdata['Age'] = newdata['Age'].astype(int)
newdata['Age'].dtypes

#Separate Age into Age Group
bins = [0, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 120]
labels = ['0-19', '20-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50-59', '60-69', '70+']
newdata['Agerange'] = pd.cut(newdata['Age'], bins, labels = labels,include_lowest = True)
```